# Increase the precision of a formula's result in TSQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to migrate a calculation from C# to TSQL and am having some difficulties achieving the needed level of precision. An example of the formula with some problematic variables plugged in is this:

`( 6.4 + ( 10 - 6.4 ) * 0.5 ) * 0.75`

When I execute this in C# I get the result `6.1499999999999995`. 
However, if I select this in TSQL it gets rounded to `6.1500`.

Is there any way to achieve the higher level of precision in TSQL?

Comment: I think SQL Server's answer is correct.

Comment: I'm happy to admit that. The trouble is that the calculation that I'm implementing requires the C# style result.

Comment: what is your data type in C#? if you are using float type in C#, it is not accurate. always use decimal. BTW, there is no division (/) in your statement so why you think 6.149999999 is correct?!

Comment: I don't think that the number I'm aiming at is more accurate. I do however need to get that number, as the c#/javascript style inaccuracies are assumed by the algorithm I'm attempting to reproduce. Perhaps someday, I'll have enough pull at Forum of Incident Response and Security Teams to propose a better path. But till then, I'm stuck looking for a way to make sql behave more like c#/javascript in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a

```
CAST(X AS DECIMAL(y,s))
```

where X is the column and y is the precision. 38 is the maximum presision you can use. s is the number of values to the right of the decimal point.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know how I might use this to get the result I'm looking for? I've tried casting every individual variable to a decimal and that didn't work. Nor did the more simple approach `SELECT CAST((( 6.4 + ( 10 - 6.4 ) * 0.5 ) * 0.75) AS DECIMAL(38, 37))`

Comment: I am not able to test atm but I just added the second parameter in my answer which defines the number of values to the right of the decimal point. Can you try to cast the first value with some value of s that you want? I guess this should make the entire statement a decimal.

Comment: I've tried casting the whole formula with the second variable added (`DECIMAL(38,37)`. When you say " Can you try to cast the first value" do you mean just 6.4?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. However, just doing the calculation on paper: 6.15 should actually be the more precise result, shouldn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the result I'm getting from different combinations of casting are just added decimal places without the increase precision. e.g. 6.150000000000000000000000000000

Comment: But this the correct result actually. I rather think the result you got from C# is off.

Comment: It might be the correct or more precise result, however, it throws a monkey wrench in the calculation I'm trying to implement, which requires rounding down from 6.1499999999999995 to 6.1. Not sure why C# (and js) gets a different result than sql, but it would be great if I could mimic it.

Comment: You can try using the Decimal type in your C# code, just use 6.4**m** instead of just 6.4 for the literals in your code.

Comment: Kateract's post is a good explanation as to why this is. I would rather try to use the more precise result in C# as well. You might cast the first number to decimal, so you get the correct result. (6.4m + (10m - 6.4m) * 0.5m) * 0.75m; Why do you want to round it down? If you always want to round down, just use the Floor function. Otherwise the correct rounding would be CAST((6.4 + ( 10 - 6.4 ) * 0.5 ) * 0.75 AS DECIMAL(18,1))

Comment: That would be the floor version: CAST(FLOOR((6.4 + ( 10 - 6.4 ) * 0.5 ) * 0.75 * 10) AS DECIMAL) / 10

Comment: The reasons for this rounding are pretty abstruse. I'm implementing a sql equivalent of this cvss calculator: https://www.first.org/cvss/v2/guide